# Trying to install jdk8 but it says its already installed (Windows 10)

Tags: java, installation, java-8

I have jdk-19 installed in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19
I previously had jdk-8, specifically jdk-8u351 which uninstalled with the java uninstaller tool.
Problem: I want to now install that same version of jdk-8 again.

I double click the jdk-8u351-windows-x64.exe file, expecting it to just install like the first time I did it, however it gives me a prompt saying that I already have it installed.

Now strangely the java uninstall tool cannot find my jdk-19, or any for jdk that matter "No Java Versions Detected". IntelliJ is still able to use my jdk-19 while this is the case

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd and type java -version
If jdk-8 is still the detected module, remove it from the [PATH](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

If the problem still occours make sure to check your installation directory if there are remainding files (sometimes, when for example the uninstaller was ran with non administrative rights it can fail)